# Laravel 5.4, renaming users table column

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

So today I tried to modify the default auth in my laravel project.

First of all: Composer (1.4.2) and Laravel (5.4.27) (meaning also all dependencies) are up to date. I verified this with:

```
composer self-update
composer update
```

---

Then I altered the users table via a migration:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $users){
    $users->string('login', 16)->unique()->after('id');
    $users->string('real_name', 32)->after('email');
});

Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $users){
    $users->dropColumn([
        'name'
    ]);
});
```

The important part of that is that I want to use 'login' instead of 'name'.

Next thing I did was modifying the User class as follows:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'login',
    'email',
    'real_name',
    'password'
];
protected $primaryKey = 'login';

public function getAuthIdentifierName()
{
    return 'login';
}
```

And also the LoginController:

```
public function username()
{
    return 'login';
}
protected function validateLogin(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        $this->username() => 'required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);
}
```

Finally I changed the login view:

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('login') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
    <label for="login" class="col-md-4 control-label">Login</label>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="login" type="text" class="form-control" name="login" value="{{ old('login') }}" required autofocus>

        @if ($errors->has('login'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('login') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Now I should have a working authentication, right? That's what I thought.

The login itself works but when it comes to reading the value of the field 'login' it fails - or something like this.

debug-bar told me the following:

The query which will be executed on login is:

```
select * from `users` where `login` = 'admin' limit 1
```

Which is loading all the data correctly except of 'login'. For some reason this field stays '0' (in auth web)

```
"user" => array:10 [
    "id" => 1
    "email" => "email@email.com"
    "created_at" => "2017-06-16 03:08:43"
    "updated_at" => "2017-06-16 03:08:43"
    "login" => 0
    "real_name" => "PolluX"
```

And when it finally comes to displaying the default home view the executed query is:

```
select * from `users` where `login` = '0' limit 1
```

---

I'm using XAMPP v3.2.2, PHP 7.1.1 and 10.2.6-MariaDB as my local dev environment on Windows 10. I should mention that I replaced the default shipped MariaDB of this XAMPP version with a fresh download of the latest stable MariaDB version. (because of an error of the migration thing)

---

I also checked multiple posts on the auth thing on StackOverflow, Laracasts and so on but didn't find any post that could've helped me.

e.g. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/change-name-column-to-username-in-auth

Comment: `protected $primaryKey = 'login';` delete that, you have primary key as **id**... same goes for `getAuthIdentifierName()` method. Migrations: If you have already some users use rename method, if you don't have any users and you are still in development, forget about new migrations just alter default one.

Comment: That did it, thank you! :)

Comment: @Kyslik Leave your comment as an answer! That way, more people with this same question can see the answer faster!

Comment: @Jsleshem I think that this question is simply lack of documentation time. Maybe I will write an extended version tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: No problem, thanks in advance for the extended answer!

Comment: @Jsleshem there you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for OP.

Delete the code `protected $primaryKey = 'login'` and `getAuthIdentifierName()` method.

All you have to do is override (add) `username()` method in the controller.

---

Note for migrations and how to do it right:

1. always use migrations to create and update database schema
2. if you are *a lone developer* AND *there is **no** production environment set up*, just amend the migrations and do database reset (remove all tables) + migrate
3. if you are *a team* OR *there is production environment already set up*, always create new migration
4. do not bother with `down()` method that much

Some material from creator & friends of Laravel regarding migrations can be heard in this podcast http://www.laravelpodcast.com/episodes/68236-episode-53-bigger-better around 30 minute mark.