# Artisan rollback, Undefined index (file missing)

Tags: laravel, rollback, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to do a rollback in Laravel 5.4. I deleted a file manually from the migrations folder. Now when I try to rollback I get an error:

```
[root@xxx]# php artisan migrate:rollback
    [ErrorException]
    Undefined index: 2017_08_22_204640_create_tasks_table
```

That file was a test (with a controller and a view), but I'm new on Laravel and didn't know that deleting that file manually would be a problem.

How can repair that now?

Edit: The main goal is to rename a column from a table made with migrations.

I made this migration file:

```
[root@xxx]# php artisan make:migration rename_nombre_generadora_column --table="admin_generadora" --create
    Created Migration: 2017_08_24_160600_rename_nombre_generadora_column
```

But then I saw that the name of the table was wrong, should be `admin_generadoras`. I wanted to create a new migration file but I got this error:

```
[root@xxx]# php artisan make:migration rename_nombre_generadora_column --table="admin_generadoras" --create


[InvalidArgumentException]
A RenameNombreGeneradoraColumn migration already exists.
```

So how can I undo that migration?

Comment: So do you need to do a rollback of that migration or not? You can open up database and view migrations table, in that table you may get an idea what is going on; if you have deleted a migration file (that has been applied) delete corresponding row in database (migrations table).

Comment: I will edit my question, I'm having trouble with 2 things

Answer (score 4):

In situations like this I always tend to simply delete whole database and run "correct" migrations again. You have seeds right? You have factories right?

I copy some text I have written [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45467619/1564365):

Note for migrations and how to do it right (IMHO):

1. always use migrations to create and update database schema
2. if you are *a lone developer* AND *there is **no** production environment set up*, just amend the migrations and do database reset (remove all tables) + migrate
3. if you are *a team* OR *there is production environment already set up*, always create new migration
4. do not bother with `down()` method that much

Some material from creator & friends of Laravel regarding migrations can be heard in this podcast http://www.laravelpodcast.com/episodes/68236-episode-53-bigger-better around 30 minute mark.

---

What you need to do now is to **understand** deeply how migrations work! To do that you need to take a look at migrations table and play with it; play with artisan and migrations related commands. And remember you can update/amend database schema with SQL (that means using some kind of database client like PhpMyAdmin) but also amend/update corresponding migration.

Answer (score 2):

the `--table` flag just helps you fill out the migration file faster.  Just go in to the `RenameNombreGeneradoraColumn` file and change `admin_generadora` to `admin_generadoras`